# $.getJSON suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I made a weather app. using free APIs and retrieving their JSONs with $.getJSON and using callback functions so that the first JSON finishes before the second so that I can store the values that I need before proceeding to the next instruction. It was working for like 3 days and I checked on it today and it just suddenly stopped working. Nothing gets processed with the first $.getJSON, tried consoling inside the function to check and nothing. Thank you for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var location, temperature, region, weather;
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(ipData, ipStatus, xhr){
  if(ipStatus == "success")
            console.log("External content loaded successfully!");
  if(ipStatus == "error")
            console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);

location = ipData.city + ", " + ipData.region;
region = ipData.region;
 console.log(region);

$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "&type=accurate&units=metric&appid=166d250001819b0da20d5c60a03fcc7b", function(data, status, xhr){
        if(status == "success")
            console.log("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(status == "error")
            console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    console.log(data);
 
temperature = Math.round(data.main.temp);
 weather = data.weather[0].main;
 
  $("#location").html(location); $("#temperature").html(temperature + '' + '°');
  $("#temperature").append('<span id="type">C</span>');
 $("#temperature").on('click',"span#type", changeNotation);
  
 function changeNotation(){
   var tempEl = $("#temperature");
   var tempC = temperature, tempF = Math.round((tempC * 9 / 5) + 32);
   var el = $("#type"),
       notation = $("#type").text().trim();
  if( notation == 'C'){
      tempEl.html(tempF + '°' + '<span id="type">F</span>');
  }else if(notation == 'F'){
      tempEl.html(tempC + '' + '°' + '<span id="type">C</span>');
  }
}

changeBackground(weather, region);
    
function changeBackground(weather, region){
  var elImg = $("#img");
 var noNewYork = false;
  console.log(weather);
  switch(true){
   case weather == 'Clear' && region == 'NY':
  elImg.css("background-image", "url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/544ff5d2e4b0f5f55c912ba3/t/5457bfa5e4b0317a94783016/1415036844256/NYSkyline_Sunny_crop.jpg?format=2500w)");
   break;
   case weather == 'Rain' && region == 'NY':
    elImg.css("background-image","url(http://cdn.citylab.com/media/img/citylab/2014/10/5969979038_c7fe5b0d81_b/lead_large.jpg)");
     break;
   case weather == 'Clouds' && region == 'NY':
     elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://pics4.city-data.com/cpicv/vfiles1486.jpg)");
     break;
   case weather == 'Snow' && region == 'NY':
     elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://static6.businessinsider.com/image/511669e869bedda03e000013-1200/snowstorm-february-2013-manhattan-ny-uws.jpg)");
     break;
    default: 
      noNewYork = true;
   
}
  if(noNewYork){
    switch(weather){
    case 'Clear':
          elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://portugalresident.com/sites/default/files/field/image/istock_sunny_sky_with_grass_000005407896small.jpg)");
     break;
        case 'Snow':
          elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://www.lewistonmaine.gov/images/pages/N541/SNOW.jpg)");
     break;
        case 'Rain':
          elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/05/28/636000076698153744-318535480_maxresdefault.jpg)");
     break;
        case 'Clouds':
          elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://www.weatherwizkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/fractus-clouds.jpg)");
        break;
      default:
        elImg.css("background-image", "url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/qQa5Pd7.jpg)");
        break;
  }
 }
}
});
});
});
```

```css
#location{
  font-size: 22px;
}
span#type{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: oblique;
}
h2{
  color: blue !important;
}
#table{
  display: table;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black !important;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:.5em;
}
body#img{
  background-size:     cover;                  
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <!docTYPE HTML> -->
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>


 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2 class="text-info"> Welcome to the <span><b>Weather App!</span></b></h2>
    <p class="text-primary bg-info text-center">
      This app. will display the weather based on your current location. Click on the C or F to toggle between celsius and fahrenheit.</p>
  </div>
 
  <body id="img">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
 <div id="table">
  <h2 class="text-center"><b> Current location </b></h2>
      <h1 class="text-center text-info" id="location"> </h1> 
    <h2 class="text-center"> <b>Current Temperature</b> </h2>
      <h1 class="text-center text-info" id='temperature'> </h1>
      </div>
      </div> 
   <div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", ....` loads correctly for me. Since this happens client side I would guess that perhaps there is a connection issue from where you are testing this. Since you are developing this and likely reloading the page frequently, perhaps they have something blocking requests from your IP on their side?

Comment: `http://ip-api.com/json` times out for me, even when visited directly, so seems it's down some places?

Comment: Yes, on their website it says they will ban ip addresses doing 150 requests per minute. But I never reloaded the page that much a minute, unless I'm mistaken with what "requests" mean. Also, even if my ip address was banned, wouldn't the console.log return the error message at least? That doesn't come up.

Comment: I don't know, I'm behind a widely used VPN, so my IP is probably banned then, and it just times out for me.

Comment: I think I am using a VPN as on this computer, I checked my other devices and they're displaying the app. fine. I'm still confused as to why the code doesn't process even if my ip address is banned.